# Java print array of integers while array is stored as an object

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a program that will take any dimension size array, determine the dimension count, then loop through the array without using two for loops. It is an assignment for class. Basically, the assignment is to process a n-D array as if it is a 1-D while keeping the array unchanged. However, to determine the dimension of the array, I have to convert it to an object. Then, I am trying to print out each array value in every space, but can't cause the array is passed in as an object. Any ideas?

```
public class Main 
{
    
    static int[][] twoDArray = {
            {5,3,6,3,7},
            {4,2,1,0,9},
            {8,2,1,9,4},
    };
    
    static int[][][] threeDArray = {
            {{2,4},{1,4},{3,4},{6,4},{7,4}},
            {{9,4},{2,4},{8,4},{9,4},{2,4}},
            {{7,4},{1,4},{5,4},{3,4},{8,4}},
    };
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        loopThroughArray(twoDArray, 3, 5, 2);
    }
    
    public static void loopThroughArray(Object arr, int xLength, int yLength,
            int zLength)
    {
        if(dimensionOf(arr) == 2)
        {
            int x = 0;
            int z = 0;
            for(int y = 0; y <= yLength; y++)
            {
                if(y == yLength && x != xLength - 1)
                {
                    y = 0;
                    x++;
                }
                if(y == yLength && x == xLength - 1)
                {
                    y = 0;
                    x = 0;
                    z++;
                    if(z == zLength) break;
                }
                //System.out.print(arr[x][y]); This line gives me an error.
            }
        }
        else if(dimensionOf(arr) == 3)
        {
            int x = 0;
            int z = 0;
            for(int y = 0; y <= yLength; y++)
            {
                if(y == yLength && x != xLength - 1)
                {
                    y = 0;
                    x++;
                }
                if(y == yLength && x == xLength - 1)
                {
                    y = 0;
                    x = 0;
                    z++;
                    if(z == zLength) break;
                }
                //System.out.print(arr[x][y][z]); This line gives me an error.
            }
        }

    }
    
    
    //This is the function that determines the dimension size of the array.
    public static int dimensionOf(Object arr) {
        int dimensionCount = 0;
        Class c = arr.getClass(); // getting the runtime class of an object
        while (c.isArray()) // check whether the object is an array
            {
            c = c.getComponentType(); // returns the class denoting the component type of the array
            dimensionCount++;
            }
        return dimensionCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the dimensionOf() function, the parameter takes in java.lang.Object's type Object, so I am simple saying I am not passing in an array how you normally would, in my case using int[][] or int[][][], etc. I am passing it in the same way through the loopThroughArray() function.

Comment: newer version of Java: `if (arr instanceof int[][] twoD) { ... twoD[i][j] ...} else if (arr instanceof int[][][] threeD) { ... threD[i][j][k] ...}` - not so actual version: `if (arr instanceof int[][]) { int[][] twoD = (int[][]) arr; ... twoD[i][j] ...} else ...`  || BTW for any dimension, you can also test `arr instanceof Object[]` to know it has at least one dimension (at least two if the *inner* one is `int[]`), or `instanceof int[]` for only one dimension

Comment: there is also `java.lang.reflect.Array` with helpful methods - I think you'll find some that fits your actual code (`get()` or `getInt()`) which take an `Object` and an `int` to retrieve the chosen element

Comment: @user16320675 This does not seem to be working. Getting an exception that says "Argument is not an array of primitive type": `System.out.print(Array.getInt(arr, x));`

Comment: that will only work if `arr` is `int[]`, but not for `int[][]` or higher dimensions (an array of arrays)

Comment: @user16320675 I have tried your other method and it does work with what I need to do, thank you!

Comment: Yes, the `instanceof` method works. Here are my new dimension checks: `if(arr instanceof int[])` and same for a 2d and 3d array. Then my prints are `int[][] twoD = (int[][])arr; System.out.print(twoD[x][y]);` I appreciate the help!

Comment: my recursive solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFVx5.png (elements must be `int`)